# Read Microsoft Excel Sheets from a Windows Store Application

Tags: excel, azure, windows-store-apps, office365, sharepoint-online

I want to develop a Windows Store app that reads data from a Microsoft Excel Sheet.

I'm looking for a solution for this, something like hosting the Excel sheet on a server and using some API or an SDK to read its content.

Also can SharePoint Online, Azure or Office 365 provide such functionality ? I didn't work with these tools before so I don't know what they can really offer for my scenario.

What can be the best solution to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the following link for SDK to read Microsoft Excel files,

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio

Regards,
Riyaj Ahamed I